# Java 7 security issues information

Tags: security, java-7

Maybe not the correct platform for a question such as this, but does anyone know where (or if) you can find out detailed information regarding the current Java 7 SE security issues, like [these ones](http://www.security-explorations.com/en/SE-2012-01-poc.html)?

I presume these are not published, as this would essentially document how to exploit the vulnerabilities, but just thought I would ask in case there is somewhere you can get some more information that expands upon *"complete Java security sandbox bypass"*.  I found [Alex Millers blog](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/) but it doesn't appear to have been updated for a couple of years.

Thanks.

Comment: You might request to have this moved to security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been my experience that moving to the latest version is generally less of a security risk than keeping with an older one.  Reason being that security researchers generally jump on the latest releases pretty quick to point out the issues.  Typically those will be resolved fairly soon.  Whereas devs rarely go back to older releases unless the problem is really widespread AND they can code a solution that doesn't break lots of apps.

The reality is that we mere mortals aren't privy to outstanding security issues for two reasons.

The first being that companies don't want to publish issues that have yet to be resolved.  The second being that black hat hackers have zero interest in publishing issues that they know about.

Quite frankly it's a given that even Oracle doesn't know all of the outstanding security issues on Java 6..  They just know the ones that the good guys have told them about, and they'll never publicly release that to us until they have released a patch for it.  Even then patch descriptions tend to obfuscate exactly what it is they are fixing.

If I was a security auditor I'd try to plug myself into those forums and sites that discuss hacking java for fun and profit and simply watch what comes across.

Comment: Well, a **big** reason why old releases are less secure is that the black hats can reverse-engineer what the problem was from the fix that was released with the new version. That's not always trivial, but in general you should assume that ever sufficiently old piece of software has several large, well-known security vulnerabilities. (And that doesn't even consider the cases where security researches do full disclosure *after* the fix was released).

Answer (score 0):

When the security researchers are responsible (and the producing companies don't sit on their respective asses for too long), then the PoCs usually only get release once the fixed version of the software is released and somewhat widely spread.

If your interest is reasearch, then older, already-released vulnerabilities should give plenty of content to research on.

If your interest is an active exploit of those vulnerabilities, then don't expect any help from me (or anyone else on this site, I hope).

Comment: Don't worry, my intentions are noble.  We are currently considering updating our application to run on SE7 from 6, and wanted to know a little more as to the current vulnerabilities, and whether it is a good idea at the minute, or wait until the next CPU in February.  I discovered that Octobers CPU from Oracle addressed all but two of the issues raised by Security Explorations (29 and 50).  Thank you for the information.